Problems installing CiviCRM on Joomla 5
Good afternoon everyone! I am attempting to install civicrm on a fresh Joomla 5 site and am receiving multiple errors during the install. I have attempted to install from a directory from the local server and have tried uploading the file from my computer. When attempting to upload from a directory, last night it would throw a critical 500 server error upon attempting to install, but today it is saying that there is no XML file or patch does not have a package. When attempting to upload directly, it will either say it does not have an XML file or it will throw a 500 internal error. I can see that civicrm is under my extensions tab but I am unable to do anything with it. If anyone has any advice or ideas to bounce off, I would appreciate it!

Welcome to SE!   Unfortunately CiviCRM does not install cleanly on J5 at the moment.  We hope to have a build fairly soon but it is possible to work around the problems in the current build.  See this issue
